# Calculate datetime with javascript in days

Tags: javascript

I have a date in datetime and I need to calculate it with the current date in javascript to check if 7 days have passed.

```js
var created_at = 2021-05-20; //return 2021-05-20 14:00:00
var data = new Date();
var dataAtual = data.getFullYear() + "-" + ("0" + (data.getMonth() + 1)).substr(-2) + "-" + ("0" + data.getDate()).substr(-2);
var result = data - created_at;
if(result < 7){
  var create_date = true;
  console.log(true);
} else {
  var created_date = false;
  console.log(false);
}
```

Comment: You're probably better of using a library like moment.js or something like that.

Comment: If you're open to using a third-party library then I recommend using MomentJS to handle date and time related calculations, more at https://momentjs.com/

Comment: What is your question? What is wrong with the code you've provided?

Comment: @Jarmod The code I provided is not calculating correctly.

Comment: You know that `var created_at = 2021-05-20;` sets the value to 1996 (2021 minus 5 minus 20), yes? Those are numbers. You can't represent a date like that. See [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: What is it supposed to do? What is `dataAtual` for? What to you think `created_at` is right now other than a math expression? I'm confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try the below code

```
var date1 = new Date('2021-05-20 14:00:00')
var date2 = new Date()
var resulu = date2.getDate() - date1.getDate()
if(result < 7){
  var create_date = true;
  console.log(true);
} else {
  var created_date = false;
  console.log(false);
}
```

Comment: Please upvote the answer if it was helpful , might help others as well

Answer (score 0):

Get the difference of dates in milliseconds and convert into days.

```js
const old_date = new Date('2021-05-20');
const today = new Date();
const diff_days = (today - old_date) / 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

if (diff_days < 7) {
  console.log('older than a week');
} else {
  console.log('in last week');
}
```